# how to combine/merge a video and a Gif using FFMPEG?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, merge, gif, combine

I want to merge a video and Gif.
My video is a picture and a song during 45 seconds and my Gif is a equalizer animation.

I want to combine video and Gif , Gif opacity be 50%.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We expect you to make an effort before asking us to solve your problem for you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://$SITEURL$/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://$SITEURL$/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i eq.gif -filter_complex "[1]format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[front];[0][front]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=H-h,format=yuv420p" output.mp4
```

Uses these filters:

- [format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) - Selects a pixel format with alpha (transparency).
- [colorchannelmixer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorchannelmixer) - Sets the alpha channel to 50%.
- [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) - Places one video over another.
- [format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) (again) - Sets a compatible pixel format. May be redundant, depending on several factors including input format and encoder, but won't hurt to include it for MP4 output.

Comment: *May be redundant* --> it is, since overlay defaults to `yuv420p` output. Shouldn't it be `auto`?